# I setup my html theme into magento 2.1.0, Css and Js file not loading

Tags: theme, magento2.1.0

I am very new to Magento 2.1.0. but want to install HTML theme (theme integration). When I `deploy static` content and also in `pub` folder I can see my .css file under **`css/source`** folder.

My theme Structure: `<VendorName>/<themeName>/web/css/source`.

and after that include my CSS and JS files into the `Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` file. Below is my code:

```
**default_head_blocks.xml**

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <css src="css/source/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <css src="css/source/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <css src="css/source/slick.css"/>
        <css src="css/source/style.css"/>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>

    </head>
</page>
```

I flush the `cache`, deploy the static content but when I see `view source` in the browser I am not able to my `CSS` and `js` file.

So can anyone help me?

```
Magento ver:2.1.0
```

Any kind of help will appreciative.

Comment: have you select your theme from admin?

Comment: Check my answer will help you.

Comment: In Magento 2, you can not see your CSS and JS in view source, for that you need to check in browser network and console tab (f12) because all these files running in the background. Better to add some CSS property and check in the frontend. Don't forget to flush the cache and to run static-content command.

Answer (score 0):

**To apply a theme:**

In Admin, go to **CONTENT > Design > Configuration**.

A Design Configuration page opens. It contains a grid with the available configuration scopes.

For example:

[image]

You need to refresh your cache  (clear cache)

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

For more information check Magento official [document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html).

Comment: yes I set the theme from the admin

Answer (score 0):

Put your custom css in below path

> /app/design/frontend/VendorName/themeName/web/css/font-awesome.min.css

And call in `Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
</page>
```

You need to run below command

> php bin/magento set:up

Comment: I used your code but I can't see any updates for css and js file.

Comment: In which XML have you put above code, please share with me full path with actual XML name

Comment: app/design/frontend/Mcardles/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml  file.

Comment: Please check once in page view source. Your CSS was showing or not. If this project live please share with me URL

Answer (score 0):

kindly run below commands

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```